# iOS Call History private API for personal Xcode use?

Tags: ios

There are many questions on how to pull iOS Call history and a common answer is "Your app will be rejected if using a private API", Which leads to a follow up question,

Under latest iOS, can the call history be used/retrieved in a self produced and deployed directly through XCode app?

I'd like to write a quick app that imports call history, time and duration into the calendar. So that I can keep track of who/when I called someone using Google Calendar. Is this possible? The App will only be deployed through Xcode to an iPhone connected to my Mac, my own phone.

My phone is not Jail Broken. I don't wish to do this.

Comment: I think you already have the answer. If the ipa is going to be signed with developer signature, u can do it i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Only when submitted to the AppStore for review can it be rejected.
The app you wrote yourself is only installed on your mobile phone and will not have this problem.